# SQL Query returning differents results

Tags: sql, azure

I have a query that gets the storeId, calculates the % of sells, % of sells from the marketplace, % of null values and than gets the total, as follows:

```
SELECT storeId,
    SUM(case when marketPlace = '0' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over () as '% Venda própria',       
    SUM(case when marketPlace <> '0'  then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over () as '% Vendar MktPlace',
    SUM(case when marketPlace IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over () as '% NULL',
    COUNT(storeId) as 'total' 
from ST_HB_Header (nolock)
WHERE
    date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-07'and
    storeId =  '904'
GROUP BY storeId
```

[image: Query Result]

It works fine when I run it with one storeId, but when I run with multiple the results change.

the only line that I changed is the following:

```
  storeId in  ('904', '552')
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I'm sure something obviously wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.
Also: running on Azure Data Studio

I've tried to do subqueries instead but took a long time to run only one storeId, so I'm trying to fix it in another way

Comment: Sometimes it's fast to `UNION` two queries, to avoid using `IN`.

Comment: What is the purpose of dividing by sum(count(*)) over ()? Keep in mind that if you return more rows in the second query, that sum will be different.

Answer (score 0):

When you include multiple storeId values in the IN clause, the GROUP BY clause groups all the rows with different storeId values together, resulting in aggregated calculations across all the storeId values.

Try this instead

```
SELECT storeId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN marketPlace = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS '% Venda própria',
    SUM(CASE WHEN marketPlace <> '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS '% Venda MktPlace',
    SUM(CASE WHEN marketPlace IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) AS '% NULL',
    COUNT(*) AS 'total' 
FROM ST_HB_Header (nolock)
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-07'
    AND storeId IN ('904', '552')
GROUP BY storeId;
```